# When I have a condition `if (bool = true)`, the else branch is never hit. Why?

Tags: javascript, assignment-operator, equality-operator

Here's the challenge:

> Create a function makePlans that accepts a string. This string should be a name. The function makePlans should call the function callFriend and return the result. callFriend accepts a boolean value and a string. Pass in the friendsAvailable variable and name to callFriend.

> Create a function callFriend that accepts a boolean value and a string. If the boolean value is true, callFriend should return the string 'Plans made with NAME this weekend'. Otherwise it should return 'Everyone is busy this weekend'.>

Here's what I wrote:

```js
let friendsAvailable = true;

function makePlans(name) {
  return callFriend(friendsAvailable, name);
}

function callFriend(bool, name) {
  if (bool = true) {
    return 'Plans made with ' + (name) + ' this weekend'
  } else {
    'Everyone is busy this weekend'
  }

}

console.log(makePlans("Mary")) // should return: "Plans made with Mary this weekend'
friendsAvailable = false;
console.log(makePlans("James")) //should return: "Everyone is busy this weekend."
```

Comment: `if (bool = true)` This *assigns* `true` to bool. You need to use `if (bool === true)` to do a comparison, or just `if (bool)`

Comment: `if (bool = true)` is **totally** useless. That's an _assignment_, not a _comparison_, so the result is always true.

Comment: In general, avoid comparing with `true` and `false`. Just write `if (bool)` or `if (!bool)`

Comment: Thanks :)  very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the `if (bool = true)` part that everyone has already pointed out (you could use `if (bool)` for this), you forgot to add `return` in `else` statement. It should be:

```
} else {
    return 'Everyone is busy this weekend'
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Complete code:

```js
let friendsAvailable = true;

function makePlans(name)
  {
  return callFriend(friendsAvailable, name);
  }

function callFriend(bool, name)
  {
  if (bool)  // or  if (bool===true), but testing if true is true is a little bit redundant
    {
    return 'Plans made with ' + (name) + ' this weekend'
    } 
  else 
    {
    return 'Everyone is busy this weekend'
    }
  }

console.log(makePlans("Mary")) // should return: "Plans made with Mary this weekend'
friendsAvailable = false;
console.log(makePlans("James")) //should return: "Everyone is busy this weekend."
```

But if you want to impress your teacher do this:

```js
const
  callFriend = 
    (bool, name) =>
      bool 
       ? `Plans made with ${name} this weekend` 
       : 'Everyone is busy this weekend' 

const makePlans = name => callFriend(friendsAvailable, name);


let friendsAvailable = true

console.log(makePlans('Mary')) 

friendsAvailable = false

console.log(makePlans('James'))
```

some helpers:
[Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
[Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: By 15krep I'd hope you knew: a code dump that explains neither what changed nor why that solved the problem isn't very useful.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I believe in the virtues of teaching by example, don't you?

Comment: If that's what your definition requires, apparently not.

Comment: @jonrsharpe j'ai pas compris, de quelle définition parlez vous ?